# How to populate the cell of a new line using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have currently built some code that, when the appropriate button is clicked, generates a new line in a table. What I would then like to happen, is this new line be updated so that the the first column (titled "Reference") is populated by the numerical value equal to the the line number.

So for example, if there were 3 lines present in the table, and the button was clicked, a new line would be inserted and the value in column one of that line would be "4".

Here is the code I have currently:

```
Private Sub Add_Equipment_Click()
'Macro to add a piece of equipment to list in subsystem sheet

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="MechEng123"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tbl_obj_row As ListRow
    Dim Row_Num As Double

'Set variables and add row
    Set ws = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
    Set tbl_obj_row = tbl.ListRows.Add

'Define the Reference of new row
    Row_Num = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    Cells(Row_Num, 1).Value = Row_Num


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="MechEng123"

End Sub
```

It is under the "Define the Reference of new row" where I am having problems. A new row is generated, but I simply can't get the reference to populate. When the code runs, I get "Run=Time Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error" with `Cells(Row_Num, 1).Value = Row_Num` highlighted.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you insert it as a Excel 'table'.. Only excel formula =ROW() is sufficient.. It will update automatically as and when you add a row to the table range

Comment: @NareshBhople - `ROW()` doesn't reflect the table row number though... you'd have to adjust it by the row # of the header range, something like `=ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers])`

Comment: @BigBen Very True... In that case the formula would be row - header row

Comment: @NareshBhople thank you for the comment, how exactly could I work that formula into my VBA code? By checking it as a formula, it returns the result "10" which is indeed the correct row number.

Comment: @T.Coates - you wouldn't add it in the VBA, you would just change that column in your table to be the formula.

Comment: @BigBen I understand. I would like to capture this all in VBA if possible, but failing that, this sounds like a good solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `ListRow` object reference - use that:

```
tbl_obj_row.Range(1).Value = Row_Num
```

Or just use a formula, e.g.

```
=ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers])
```

Comment: Hi @BigBen - I thought I would be able to use my object reference too, but apparently not!

When I set my code to:

`'Define the Reference of new row

    Row_Num = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

    tbl_obj_row.Cells(1).Value = Row_Num`

I get the same Error 1004 with the `tbl_obj_row.Cells(1).Value = Row_Num` highlighted?

Comment: Sorry - use `Range` instead of `Cells`.

Comment: So I now have: `tbl_obj_row.Range(1).Value = Row_Num` However this line of code is still being highlighted as an Error 1004. I know I must be extremely close, I can see from my locals window that the value of `Row_Num` is in fact now 4 as it should be. I just can't get the cell to update :(

Comment: What are the protection settings in the sheet? Though honestly I'd just use a formula. I can't replicate the RTE 1004 though.

Comment: I do have the worksheets locked in protect mode to prevent user error, however my code: `ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="MechEng123"` should have handled this I thought. I will check though. Thank you for all your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Update! Huge thank you to Ben above!

The issue was in my worksheet protections. I needed an additional:

`ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="MechEng123"`

Line of code immediately prior to the

`tbl_obj_row.Range(1).Value = Row_Num`

As the active sheet had been re-locked through the calling of another macro.

Thank you again to everyone for taking the time to help me with this issue!